# Avoid Marker (Google Maps for Android API V2) to center itself on map on click

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, centering, android-maps-v2

I have geolocated events in my Map that I'm adding with Markers, and when I click on them, I just want them to change without being centered.

Is there any way to override the markers being centered (and onCameraChanged being called) when I click on a Marker?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `OnMarkerClickListener` to the `GoogleMap` and return `true` in `onMarkerClick`.

Comment: This does not work when you want to show an info window - if you return `true`, the info window will not show itself, because you override the default behavior.

Comment: @MichalKottman You do marker.showInfoWindow() **and** return true.

Comment: Yes, I should have done more research before ranting. `marker.showInfoWindow()` does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I have that problem when i use clustering. There is no showInfoWindow with clustering. Any help?